# How many territories are there?

Tags: ufo-afterlight

I'm not sure there's much to add to the title: I'm playing Afterlight. I've got about 45 territories and would like to know how many are left.

I'd open up the data file and look at the territory.txt myself, but my extracter is misbehaving.

Comment: Does it matter? There's no benefit to having a certain number of territories. They do entirely cover the planet, however.

Comment: Well, knowing that I've (for example) taken 75% of the globe before the end of the early game would indicate that I've overstretched myself somewhat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I grabbed a new extracter and discovered that there are 79 territories in total. Owning 56% of the map during the mid-game seems reasonable.